# Should there be a minimum size to revisons?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, edits

I just saw someone edit [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24627008/494643), changing the title from "Rearrange an array such that when written..." to "Rearrange an array so when written...", with the note that they fixed the grammar in the title. That didn't look right to me, so I changed the "so" to "so that". And ten I thought, this is an incredibly minor, petty change, which is really not worth anyone wasting time on, but it marks the question visibly as having been edited - making it look like it has been modified, possibly substantially.

It seems to me, there should be some sort of restriction to prevent excessively minor edits. For instance, have edits of less than X characters placed in a separate review queue marked minor, perhaps which have [a different reputation impact](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253123/494643).

Maybe also include an indicator on the post itself showing how much of it is left of the original, so we can see at a glance how much of the visible post was originally published.

Comment: There is one such limitation already: suggested edits must be at least 6 characters.

Comment: Related: [Prevent minor and invalid edits better](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255478/464709), [Is it okay to make minor edits once I have 2k rep?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191090/164403)

Comment: you can clearly see the changes made if you check out the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24627008/revisions)

Comment: The edit in question wasn't a suggested edit, so the editor wasn't bound to a specific minimum size.  That is one of the privileges granted to users with full edit privileges.

Answer (score 4):

Yes that was a small edit and was probably not the most urgent, but the user felt that it made the title more readable.  I wouldn't have made that same edit, but I don't think he made the post any worse with the edit.  Your edit to fix his edit was similarly unnecessary.  I don't think anything really needed fixing there, but of the 3 variations, the original title was by far the worst since it is an inappropriate use of the word "when".

And just the same as you, the editor had 2K rep, so they were not bound by any minimum edit length.  **Suggested** edits made by users with less the 2K rep have a minimum of 6 characters and much of that restriction is to prevent users from wasting reviewers time approving tiny edits.  Since 2K users don't need reviewers, there isn't anyone's time to waste.  Yes it did bump the post, which is why I wouldn't have made the edit, but as long as the user isn't bumping dozens of posts with the same edit, I fail to see the problem.

> It seems to me, there should be some sort of restriction to prevent excessively minor edits. For instance, have edits of less than X characters placed in a separate review queue marked minor, perhaps which have a different reputation impact.

This is already handled.  Users who make suggested edits and earn rep from such edits cannot make minor edits as I mentioned above.  There is no need for any additional features to deal with it.  For users with >2K rep and have full edit privileges don't have a review queue because we trust them to make good edits.  Sometimes that trust is misplaced, but forcing small edits from these users to go into a review queue adds unnecessary burden to the system and actually will waste far more time than just allowing the small edit as you now will need people to review the small edit.

> Maybe also include an indicator on the post itself showing how much of it is left of the original, so we can see at a glance how much of the visible post was originally published.

What is the benefit of this?  I don't see a use-case where it is necessary to know what percentage of the original post is left.  There are times when it might be useful to know what was edited (and why), and for that you have the revision history.  But I certainly don't see a need to know a percentage of the changes when viewing the question, as the content and quality of the edit is what is important not the **quantity**.

Comment: That's true. I think the main things I was thinking, were a) that marking a question as having been edited makes it look like it might be different from the original question, and you can't tell how much it might have changed without reviewing the edits, and b) that 5 edits turns a question into community wiki (although I don't know if this is still true?)

Comment: @Benubird automatic CW doesn't exist anymore, and when it existed, it was edits by 5 different people, not 5 edits.  It took 10 edits overall.  But the question was edited, and a new revision was generated.  But regardless, if you feel so strongly about the extra revision, why did you make your edit?

Comment: Because an edit had already been made. my reluctance is not really about minor edits in general, but about allowing a question to be marked as "edited". So once the first person edits it, there's no reason to to make additional minor edits.

Comment: @Benubird if this is about just having an "edited" link for a small edit, then I think you are focusing on the wrong problem.  Minor edits in general are frowned upon, whether it is the 1st, 2nd or 12th revision to the post.  However, there could be necessary minor edits that are impossible to distinguish from unnecessary minor edits by a computer, so we have to trust the users who have the privileges to make edits are making useful edits,

Comment: Looks like this idea has been implemented.  So now I can't correct [an incorrect spelling of Bernoulli in an answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/513204/226254) so that it comes up in searches!