# Please don't just approve trivial suggested edits - rather improve the edit per the scope

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Editing a question/answer is good, as far as it makes some sense and really improves the post. Reviewing a suggested edit is a responsibility and not just a matter of formality.

A **single-character edit** such as [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7930119), which actually is just adding a question-mark is annoying and adds *nothing*. Moreover, it gets blindly approved without improving the edit.

For reference, this is the **original question**:
https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30023028/1 which had the scope of improvement like:

- Formatting the code
- Grammar in the body
- Spelling mistakes

[image]

If you see, it first got **approved** by two reviewers, and then approved by **Community**. And what exactly was the suggested edit? *A question mark was added to the topic title*, and *that's it*!

There are following options:

- Improve Edit
- Reject and Edit
- Reject
- Skip

If you see a scope to improve, please do improve the edit and do not just click on approve.

If you do not see any scope to improve the edit, and that the suggested edit is trivial, then reject it.

Please do not blindly approve trivial suggested edits. Do something about it, if you find something could be done about it.

---

**Update: Regarding a specific case when there is no scope of improving a suggested edit:**

I understand when there is a single-character edit like adding a question-mark only is not going to harm the post and thus folks would just approve it.

But, wouldn't this encourage the editor to do such trivial edits in the future and then we would see a pile of posts in the Review stack for Suggested Edits. I wish the editor is made aware of it. As we don't know if this might be an attempt to gain the +2 reputation for getting a suggested edit approved.

So, the specific case in the update might be worth another discussion. However, regarding the **original question**, my opinion is that the **review** should have been to **Improve Edit** and not just **Approved**.

---

**Edit: Regarding the question marked as duplicate**

The duplicate marked question, ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site) has a highest voted answer with a conclusion:

> We should allow people to correct grammar and spelling mistakes. We
>   don't have to be obsessive about it, but if someone is willing to
>   spend the time for that kind of edit, let them.

Ok, correction of grammar and spelling mistakes is still improving something. However, as I posted an example about **adding a question mark only** to the topic title **doesn't improve anything** and simply **approving the suggested edit** is a **poor judgement**. If the suggested edit would have been correction of a spelling mistake, I would not have posted my question at all. So, I don't agree this is a duplicate question as we are addressing two different kinds of edits; I am concerned about **addition** a single-character, and the other question marked as duplicate addresses the **modification**.

Another question, *[When an edit only fixes a typo, what should I do as a reviewer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253123/when-an-edit-only-fixes-a-typo-what-should-i-do-as-a-reviewer)* also talks about fixing a typo. As I said, my concern is not about *fixing typos*, or *correcting spelling mistakes* or *grammar*, but a *single-character addition* in the topic title and then being approved by the reviewers without improving the edit.

---

**Update 2: Regarding the debate about the grammar**

For those who think the edit to add a *question-mark* to original question (*How to do multiple record updation in oracle*) in the posted example is correct, then please understand that it actually makes it grammatically incorrect. Please read [Why do my “How to” questions often get renamed to “How do I”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/20730/why-do-my-how-to-questions-often-get-renamed-to-how-do-i)

---

**NOTE**: Reading the comments thoroughly, it seems that there might be a confusion between actually **suggesting an edit** versus **approving the edit**. Please see this [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30023028/1), and then compare it with the edited question as it looks now. Please take some time to look at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30023028/revisions) before making any opinion.

I completely agree with the downvotes, that it is a disagreement. However, it shouldn't be at the cost of misunderstanding. So, please look at the edits and updates to the question. I have tried my best to address each and every concern.

Comment: You know what, I've always wondered if us mods should post more PSAs like this...

Comment: @BoltClock At first, I thought to leave a comment in the question suggesting my opinion to the editor and reviewers, but then I found it important to post it here at meta. Because, next time I will post a link to redirect them here to make them understand better.

Comment: Let's assume that there's no room for more edits in that question except for the question mark. Would you still approve it? If it was me, I would differently have added the question mark, the question is.. Why should I disapprove it if I would had added it myself? (again, if it was the only edit that should be done).

Comment: @MarounMaroun I don't see a reason to approve a "question mark only" addition as an edit. By the way, this question had a scope of improvement and a reviewer did try and improve the edit.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I agree with *that* specific question, but I would like to know if you would had approved it if it was the *only* edit that should be done to the question.

Comment: @MarounMaroun No, as I said, I don't see a reason to approve a "question mark only" addition as an edit. And it is my personal opinion.

Comment: I think I agree with what Maroun Maroun is getting at—I thought the only reason we were rejecting ‘trivial’ edits is if it wasn’t going far enough to improve the post. If, however, it’s nearly perfect and a ‘trivial’ edit makes it perfect, I see no reason to reject it.

Comment: Huh? I thought that edits( <2K rep ) has to be at least 6 or 7 characters long.

Comment: @CoolGuy Well, the last editor might have changed it (which is why it was approved by Community), he still marked the edit as helpful?

Comment: I would've chosen "Reject and Edit", or "Reject" if there was nothing else to edit. The question mark in the title is almost completely redundant.

Comment: It should have been Reject and Edit, 'updation' is not a word.

Comment: Following the guidelines given in the MSE FAQ on good question titles (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647) the title should have received a complete rewording, instead of an additional, (imo) redundant question mark.

Comment: @NisseEngström Not just redundant, it actually breaks the grammar, because that title isn't phrased as a question.

Comment: @CoolGuy Edits to the post body have to be at least 6 characters. Editing tags or titles don't have the same restriction.

Comment: @moooeeeep As you suggested the possible duplicate, and that the question is now marked as duplicate, I have added an edit to the question as a disagreement. Thanks.

Comment: @moooeeeep Thanks, you could vote to reopen then.

Comment: Saying that this isn't a duplicate because the issue it duplicates does not focus on the quantitative aspects of the change (i.e. 1 character) is a bit absurd. If a word has a single character misspelling, is that suddenly too trivial to accept an edit without additional "improvements"?

Comment: @BrianTopping It is not a misspelled word, it is *adding* a single-character which make sit trivial.

Comment: Are there any exceptions, say, for when there's a full moon? The absurdity of all this is rather unbelievable. It does nothing to improve the quality of the site and distracts from more important questions.

Comment: @BrianTopping So what is your opinion?

Comment: Less is better. Strive to *refine existing rules*, not create new ones. As such, the issue this duplicates should be improved with your comments instead of creating new issues like this one. The moment one finds themselves defending their differences, they should also be asking whether they could be integrated as a "better same".

Comment: *Strive to refine existing rules, not create new ones* And why do you think I am advocating to create new rules? I am just saying that we already have the well-defined rules(rather alternatives) like *improve edit*, *reject and edit* etc. So, when it fits in the existing rules, why not judge properly and make use of the alternatives.

Comment: There's an implication that people will follow the rules. Meta on meta adds nothing. It seems the basis of the OP is that you are annoyed by having to approve trivial edits. I can appreciate that, maybe the answer is for the system to do some basic semantic analysis and decide if there is a semantic change and only queue when there is.

Comment: I'm not a native engish speaker, but adding a question mark to a "How to ..." title is not a grammatical improvement. It's wrong, because "How to ..." is a statement and not a question.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Exactly. Question mark is appropriate for *How do I* Perhaps the 20 downvoters don't understand this.

Comment: Surely this post is a rant. The real issue is that the grammar of the title is incorrect and that should have been the subject of the edit. From ```How to do multiple record updation in oracle``` to something akin to ```What's the best approach to multiple record updates in Oracle?``` or ```How should I go about updation multiple records in Oracle?```

Comment: @IanLewis What is ranting in this post? To ask not to approve an inappropriate edit? Rather improve the edit to genuinely review.

Comment: @Lalit, so what? What shall we do? Except rewording the title, there's not much to improve on that question. I've seen many fellows suggesting and approving edits like this (and some of them were approved just because the people were from the same country, I guess).

Comment: @TLama *Except rewording the title, there's not much to improve on that question.*  Did you even look at the edit history? If not, then this is how the original question looked like http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30023028/1 And now look at the question. There was a scope of improvement, like formatting the code, grammar in the body, spelling mistakes.

Comment: @Lalit, I'm sorry. I should have take a look closer (the review shows it formatted). Taking back my comment...

Comment: @TLama No problem buddy. I have added a link to the original question, just in case if someone gets confused. Probably, the 23 downvotes might be because of similar confusion.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I would say that this post is a rant because the initial point of it is purely to complain without suggesting a proper grammatically correct solution. Additionally later on in the post there is use of exclamation marks which is another indication of ranting. The OP is correct that a single character edit (in this case) was incorrect but totally fails to note that the grammatical construction of the question title is wrong.

Comment: In my original comment above an error crept in. In the second I meant to suggest ```How should I go about updating multiple records in Oracle?``` rather than the original garbled version using the non-word 'updation'. Apologies, as I can't edit my original.

Comment: @IanLewis That's the reason I added an update *Update 2: Regarding the debate about the grammar*

Comment: Minor edits should be fine, this isn't a great edit, but it shouldn't be rejected. If the problem is that it'll get added to the recently updated pile or something else, that's a problem with the recently edited filter. This is an example of a rather redundant edit, but many one character edits are just as valid.

Comment: @TankorSmash *but it shouldn't be rejected.* Did you even look at the original question? Are you sure the example in the question had an appropriate review for the suggested edit? The one-character edit as an addition of question mark actually made the edit even worse. Please follow the original question link, and the complete description in the question.

Comment: An improvement is an improvement, no matter how big or small it may be.

Comment: @j08691 - If it is an improvement at all.

Comment: And [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8035779) is another one, what the hell is 'upgradation'?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8238708) 'editor' (and all those responsible for approval) should be perma-banned from such activities for multiple crimes against the English language.

Comment: R.I.P English...

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my opinion, a single trailing question mark in the title is never worth an edit. Following the guidelines given in the MSE FAQ on good question titles ([How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647)) the title should have received a complete rewording instead of an additional, redundant question mark. (Readers should be assumed to *"understand your titles are questions."*)
So, yes, this edit adds no improvement whatsoever (and I would likely have rejected and edited it myself).

As for the *too minor edits* debate in general, I think especially new editors should be pointed more effectively (or more often, depending on the number of trivial edits they suggest) to the [edit privilege description page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> **When should I edit posts?**
>
> Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged!
>
> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks
>
> **Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.**

As a suggestion to raise both reviewer's and editor's awareness of the issue I have posted a suggestion that addresses the issue. It is intended to make reviewers think about their action by requiring them to tick a reason *why* the edit should be approved:

- [Can we make approving suggested edits harder?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292368/1025391)

Feel free to criticize.

Comment: I am unable to conclude, however I find your opinion to quite close to what I think. So marking it as an answer. I see 39 upvotes and 14 downvotes. Certainly 14 users defer from my thoughts, and they think it doesn't matter for them to have a pile of questions with a single character edit in the suggested edits stack. I think they are the ones who also approve them blindly.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Generally, I would not expect blind approvers (of *anything*) to be on Meta.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Generally, I wouldn't expect them on any site. Because if they fail, then it is a poor review and poor judgement.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Not quite sure what you mean; there are presumably a fair number of near-blind reviewers on SO proper, but very few of them would be found on Meta because that's too much effort.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Nothing fancy. What I mean is, I wish we not only have good review here at Meta, but also on the rest other sites as well.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Since there are no suggested edits on Meta to speak of, I was referring to *SO* reviewers coming to read Meta, not review it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy :-)

Answer (score 28):

> If you see a scope to improve, please do improve the edit and do not just click on approve.

That's what happened here. [Florin Ghita did improve the edit.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30023028/revisions) This shows up as two consecutive but separate edits, one by the author of the edit suggestion, and one by the person making an improvement, so that credit is given where credit is due. It wouldn't be right for Florin Ghita's improvement to show up as part of Deepak Keynes's edit suggestion.

Comment: So you don't think it should have been "Reject and Edit"? What about the first two, who selected "Approve" without any additional edits?

Comment: @Brian I wish "Too minor" would be re-introduced as an edit suggestion rejection reason, but for now, approving and improving is exactly what we're supposed to do. As for approving without improving, I really don't know. I'm not saying I think it's right, nor that I think it's wrong, I just really don't know.

Comment: @hvd I know Florin Ghita did improve the edit, but the question is why did the first two reviewers just approved and didn't improve. And that's why community robo-user approved it too. That's why I didn't like the way the suggested edit was blindly approved when there was more scope/room for improvement.

Comment: @hvd Please see my edit in the question.

Comment: @LalitKumarB No, that isn't why the community robo-user approved it. The community robo-user approved it because the third reviewer chose to accept and improve. That instantly accepts the pending suggested edit, no matter how the earlier reviewers voted. About the fact that the two earlier reviewers approved it: see my reply to Brian's comment: I don't know about that. Even if those two reviewers had rejected it, the third reviewer accepting and improving would have led to the edit suggestion being accepted anyway.

Comment: @hvd You mean the reviewers' history is not sorted? The reviewer who improved the edit did it at last, however, it shows robo-user approved before that. Anyway, don't know why people voted to close it as duplicate though, I don't see it as duplicate at all.

Comment: @LalitKumarB The user who chooses to accept and improve is typically not a diamond moderator, so cannot instantly accept the pending suggestion. That's why the system uses the Community user for that. If you hover over the timestamps ("yesterday"), you'll see "Florin Ghita reviewed this yesterday [2015-05-04 05:22:42Z]: Edit", and
"Community♦ reviewed this yesterday [2015-05-04 05:22:42Z]: Approve" It's the exact same second, and that's no coincidence.

Comment: @hvd Difficult to say. Perhaps, it is something like 3 out of 5 voted to approve, first two approved, the third reviewer improved edit, thus 3 out of 5 finally approved, thus community instantly approved it with no more delay. I am just guessing. And the fact still remains open that the first two reviewers should have improved the edit rather than instantly approving it.

Comment: @LalitKumarB No. I'm not making random guesses here, I'm *telling* you that that's how the system works.

Comment: I understand. That tells the reason why community robo-user showed up as a reviewer who approved. I think we could conclude that in my example, the first two reviews should have been an improve edit rather than just approving.

Answer (score 15):

I partially agree with you.

In that specific question, I agree that the reviewer should have improved the edit because there are other things that should be improved.

If I came across similar question, that adding the question mark was the **only** improvement that should be done, I would have edited it. Hence, if I were reviewing a post that suggested the **only** available edit (which is, for example only adding a question mark), I will definitely approved it.

Comment: Wouldn't this encourage the editor to do such trivial edits and then we would see a pile of posts in the Review stack for Suggested Edits. I wish the editor is made aware of it.

Comment: Also, it might be an attempt to gain the +2 reputation for getting a suggested edit approved.

Comment: @LalitKumarB As I said, I will *not* approve trivial edits that attempts to edit just for the +2. However, if it's the only available edit, and it's not redundant, I will approve it.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer. +1 for your *partial* agreement. Perhaps, your specific scenario is worth another discussion, but in this case it should have been an *Improve Edit*.

Comment: @LalitKumarB It's always good to discuss and hear other's opinions, thanks for bringing this interesting topic.

Comment: That question mark doesn't seem to belong there at all. The title wasn't phrased as a question.

Comment: @canon The particular grammar mistake is pretty common among non-native-English speakers when their native language doesn't conjugate verbs in the same way - using "to do" instead of the right form.  So it does read as a question to me, just that the edit should've fixed that as well

Comment: But then you would be losing a review vote in something trivial (that probably would be approved anyway), that you could have used in something more important later. As discussed on this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292007/how-to-encourage-attentive-suggested-edit-reviewers-to-skip-every-non-essential

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro It's important, any edit that improves the question is important for me.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: As the author of the linked question, I'm not sure your disagreement really addresses the case for which I wrote it. All good edits are important, *but not all important edits need your attention to succeed*, and the attention of good reviewers in Suggested Edits is sorely needed on many other edits.

Answer (score 3):

The purported justification for not allowing single-character and other trivial edits is that it makes unnecessary work for the review queue. It seems that the message hasn't got through to the review queue.

In fact there are many, many people ready and waiting to review trivial edits, and it then becomes necessary to forbid them from doing so, in case their willingness encourages the posting of such edits.

Comment: Seriously, the paradox is mind-boggling.  The system is created to award Internet Points to people who fix problems.  Then when people attempt to fix problems, they are rejected and punished and shamed--for doing what the system was created to encourage.  It seems that what's going on is, a certain mindset takes hold among those who reach the upper echelon, one in which they, in effect, defend their territory and status from those who would approach their level by *doing what they did*--that is, by doing what the system was created to reward.  Internet Points are a Bad Thing.

Comment: @blujay: No, they aren't punished for doing what the system was created to encourage. They just should not be rewarded for failing while trying (No "A" for effort), and if they fail consistently (and the reviewers *don't*), they are for a short time barred from keeping failing, which time they hopefully use to learn how and why they failed (Not only the mechanical part, but the intent.). If you see rep as what it is, a *very* rough and imperfect measure of the community's trust in your judgement, not increasing it for failing (or even decreasing it, but we won't go there) is the right thing.

Comment: @Deduplicator What in the world are you talking about?  Said people are not "failing while trying"--they are *fixing problems*!  They are *making improvements*!  They are leaving things in a state better than they found them in!  "Failing"?  Really?!

Comment: @blujay: If their suggested edit isn't worth it, how else would you characterize it than "failure"?

Comment: @Deduplicator You are completely missing the point.  Their suggested edit *is* worth it, because it is an *improvement.*  Making something better is a *good* thing.  The *failure* is on the part of elitists who reject others' work as "not worth it" in order to protect their elite status (which they attained by doing the same work they now reject from others).  Additional failure is on the part of said elitists who fail to recognize the irony in their hypocrisy.

Comment: @blujay: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1843773) is an improvement? No, even hell no! The work created for the review-queue, and bumping the post for adding *a single questionmark to the title*, is in no way justified for that pedantery on punctuation in titles. Especially considering that the question needed *lots* of *substantial* editing (see the full revision-history), which also meant completely rewriting the title, thus discarding that change anyway!

Comment: Like jwg (who posted the answer I responded to), I am talking about this problem in general, not that specific edit that merely added a question mark (that didn't even belong).  This problem of rejecting worthwhile changes because they "aren't worthwhile *enough*" is a widespread problem on SO.

Comment: @blujay Actually, edits correcting a handful typos in a paragraph that has to be completely rewritten anyway are a widespread problem. Or otherwise doing a cosmetic change and ignoring the big fat dump right next to (or more often containing) it.