# Should I approve an edit that barely improves something

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I don't know whether [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8002014) is a permalink but the edit was to change the case of a proper noun. Technically that's an improvement but jeepers - the guy clicked edit, changed the case and saved, now it's in the review queue blah blah blah and it's not adding much.

Because of that, I'm inclined to reject it (to discourage people from making that sort of edit). But maybe we want those sorts of edits to be made so that SO is a professional resource - what's the difference between calling talking about `visual basic` instead of `Visual Basic` and writing "thanks for the help guys" at the end of the question (instead of leaving it off)?

[Edit] Just to clarify, I didn't know what to do so I hit `skip` and carried on with my life.

**[Update]**

A similar problem can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8031328) where the user is pretty much brand new to SO, has asked one question and answered four with only one upvote which means most of his reputation has come from editing questions. In this question he has added a relevant tag but ignored the fact that the rest of the question is poorly composed. I'm torn because I don't want to reward that sort of edit if it's just rep whoring, on the other hand it is a relevant tag (`skip`).

**Another Update:**

I think this question is different to the **[possible duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292243)** in that there are genuine improvements that can be made by, for example, removing "How to" from the beginning of a question or changing `pootle`'s tag wiki to call it `Pootle`. These minor edits still have questionable credibility to my mind though.

Comment: In general, yes, you should approve small edit that improves a post or tag wiki.  But I'd hardly call your example an improvement.  It really doesn't make it more readable or clarify anything.

Comment: I feel like this could also lead to "auto-edit" madness that scans all SO posts for `js` and replaces it with `Javascript` or something and then clogs up review queues.

Comment: But that's really the same idea.  Just replacing js with Javascript en masse doesn't really improve the posts to any great extent.  Same with visual basic and Visual Basic.  There is a reason suggest edits to posts have a 6 character minimum.

Comment: I didn't realise there was a minimum but I think it's too low (as evinced in the link).

Comment: The link was a tag wiki edit.  I don't think they have the same minimum?

Comment: I didn't even realise it was a tag wiki edit *shameface* - I probably would have approved it...

Comment: The "too minor" rejection reason was removed from edit review, so I think SE wants any edit that is useful to be approved.

Comment: If the guy took the time to make the edit and thinks it would make an improvement and it certainly doesn't make the post worse, and could be improving it, I think it should be approved, even if minor.

Comment: With regards to "Thanks for the help guys" would this not be considered fluff, and should be edited out, as per this post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions

Comment: With regards to the update, so what if he's "rep whoring"?  Is his edit helpful, or not?  If you feel that users should not gain rep for suggesting trivial edits, that's a feature-request for the dev team (and probably an easy one for them to implement, at that).  But I cannot see it being appropriate, on any level, to deliberately reject an edit that improves the quality of the content (even if only slightly) because you've decided to act as judge, jury, and executioner, conclude that someone is "rep whoring", and therefore deny them rep.  Besides, aren't we all rep whores?

Comment: I feel like the way rep functions is that it stops spam and activity that is destructive to the community so in my mind rejecting an edit that is "barely improving" the post is good for the community. I see your point though, the SO devs can easily put a lower limit on the rep required to edit stuff and it's a feature request.

Comment: Similar discussion here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292243/please-dont-just-approve-trivial-suggested-edits-rather-improve-the-edit-per-th

Comment: Thanks @LalitKumarB and I just discovered this feature-request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267311/removing-reputation-for-rejected-edits

Comment: In addition, I've proposed this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294083/reputation-gains-for-edits

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the capitalization edit was enough to improve the post. I for example didn't have to think at all about it being a technology, capitalization conveys additional meaning in language, IMO it would have been an even better edit if the word was not the first in the sentence.

It is a super minor edit but making the Stack Exchange network have the best and most easily usable repository of information is a worthwhile goal... Why leave misspellings, run together words, etc. purely because they aren't 6 characters to edit in a post that will live on for years and many users will read...The edits take a few seconds to review and approve and the site is improved incrementally...seems like a win to me. As someone with proofreading training, I always want to make minor edits but cannot fix typographical errors unless there are enough of them...

Comment: I've suffered through rejecting minor edits; sleepless nights, eye tics, the works... so I appreciate your perspective. Inappropriate indefinite articles give me the willies, and I now feel free to approve the suggestions of those with similar maladies.

Answer (score 10):

In general I'd say no. An edit should attempt to address most of the problems with the post. Just changing the capitalisation of a proper noun hardly counts as that. However, I thought that there is a six character minimum for suggested edits so it's hard to see how they managed to suggest that edit - unless it doesn't apply to tag wikis.

Perhaps the only exception would be to make a change to some code (only in an answer though!) where just a few character change could be the difference between a working solution and a failing one. Even then there are probably other improvements you could make to the post.

Comment: The edit in question was a tag wiki except edit.  Not sure if that changes your opinion

Comment: @psubsee2003 - nope. I checked what the edit was while answering.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw you were the last reject vote.  Only mentioned because you kept refering to "post" in your answer, and so it wasn't clear if you think the same for tag wikis

Comment: @psubsee2003 - Ah, I see. I started out assuming that the edit was to a question or answer :) Not sure what I could use - other than "post or tag wiki" to be all encompassing.

Comment: I must say in this particular case I would have approved the edit because it's basically a definition. The thing is that the edit is really making an improvement but it's not to do with programming, it's to do with the fact that our medium of communication is English - as opposed to "smsspeak".

Comment: @jcuenod: We always ask for _complete_ edits. IMHO the excerpt is a bit too brief. I think an edit should add a second sentence that shortly explains what Pootle can translate. Fixing capitalization is important, but I think improving the content of this too brief excerpt is more important.

Comment: It's fine to _ask_ for complete edits, but I don't see why that logic should extend to rejecting a helpful but minor/incomplete edit.  The decision to approve or reject an edit should be trivial; you ask 'Does this edit improve _anything, at all_?', and if the answer is 'Yes' then your approve the edit, otherwise you reject.  A slight improvement is better than no improvement and we're not paying by the approval here, so the idea that trivially helpful edits should be rejected wouldn't seem to have any rational basis.

Comment: I would submit that fixing any error--no matter how small--should be encouraged. Whether it be logical, factual, or even grammatical, ensuring that the content across Stack Exchange is as good and correct as possible is always a good reason for an edit. Just look at some of the content editors at Wikipedia...some go around correcting improper usage of single words across totally unrelated articles. I applaud the grammar nazis :-)

Comment: @MattHamann I completely agree with you. Furthermore, if the edit is small, it won't take more than a second to review the edit.

Comment: I have a real problem with the insistence that "an edit should attempt to address most of the problems with the post," as though an edit should be rejected just because other problems remain. The question is, "Does this edit represent an improvement worth making?" on its own merit, not in the context of other remaining problems. We already [had this debate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253512/1394393), though.

Comment: @jpmc26 in this case the edit was just changing the capitalisation of one word. Hardly a significant improvement.

Comment: @ChrisF - Hi Chris, I think OP's question is very close(rather duplicate) to this question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292243/please-dont-just-approve-trivial-suggested-edits-rather-improve-the-edit-per-th

Comment: @ChrisF I *strongly* disagree. Number of characters changed and magnitude of improvement are not linearly related. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

In this *specific* instance, the deciding factor for me, "How do the people responsible for this product capitalize the name?" Doubly so since this is a tag wiki; it should do its best to present the technology correctly. It appears that the owners *do* capitalize the Pootle name. (See http://pootle.translatehouse.org/.) Therefore, this edit represents a significant improvement, since it brings the naming in line with  normal English mechanics *and* in line with how the name is capitalized by the owners. Failure to comply with at least one of those looks **sloppy**. Why do we want a sloppy tag wiki?

I would have approved.

The standard arguments against these kinds of edits are

- The user gets rep for doing very little, leading to the potential for abuse.

  This has nothing to do with the quality of the edit. This is a problem with the StackExchange system. The edit improves the quality, and that trumps a broken system. *Leaving low quality content* on the site is a *remarkably* poor solution to this problem.
- It can bump posts and clutter activity pages unnecessarily.

  Again, this has nothing to do with the edit on its own merits. It has everything to do with a problem with the StackExchange system. One of StackExchange's explicit goals it to create high quality content; why should we let an *activity page* interfere with that?
- It's not complete enough.

  This is nonsense. This is complaining about the *pre-existing* quality of the post. It's not the editor's fault that it was bad to begin with. We shouldn't reject a small improvement and leave even lower quality content lying around because the user didn't have days to learn the tool to provide a more complete edit. Bonus: because this edit made it on meta, the tag is *much* more likely to get a complete edit, all because this user dared to make a minor edit.

Comment: "_This is a problem with the StackExchange system_".  This.  UX problems cannot be fixed by mandating that people use the system in nonsensical ways (like "don't make minor edits" and "don't approve minor edits").  If the software can't handle minor edits gracefully, the solution is to fix the software, not to tell people that they shouldn't make/approve minor (yet helpful) edits.

Comment: Would downvoters care to explain why they disagree? I honestly don't understand the opposing view, especially given the objections I addressed. Is there something I haven't thought of?