# Reputation gains for Edits

Tags: feature-request

I've just had a look at [this feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267311/removing-reputation-for-rejected-edits) to remove reputation for rejected edits. The reason that this suggestion was rejected is that people are reluctant to reject edits and end up approving bad ones.

My suggestion is, rather than discouraging edit rejections by subtracting rep from the editor, why not block his/her reputation gains if edits are rejected.

i.e. If you propose a rejected edit you need to have 5 edits accepted before you start getting +2 rep again.

I'm particularly thinking of the <2000 rep users but I guess it could apply to users of any rep (remember >2000 rep users get rep for editing tag wikis).

Comment: If people are making mass edits for reputation how will this stop people from doing it? Won't it just mean they make more edits to get the same reputation?

Comment: They lose incentive to do useless edits that get rejected. So it encourages good, worthwhile edits.

Comment: What do you mean it could be applied across the board? Edits can't be rejected after 2k rep, because they don't go to the queue, nor do >2k rep users get +2 rep for editing. It doesn't seem like you've completely figured out what you're even proposing.

Comment: @sphanley >2k rep users get rep for tag wiki edits.

Comment: The problem is that to many bad edits get approved, having a system like this will just cause more bad edits to be suggested in the first place which will cause more bad edits to be approved. Taking longer to get the full amount of rep from edits won't discourage people who where willing to make a lot of edits in the first place.

Comment: @JoeW I'm not sure how this will make more bad edits get suggested. It will surely encourage increased quality edit suggestions with the threat that potential rep gain is seriously mitigated. All you need is one in 5 accurate edit rejections and the editor's gain is completely undermined. Making lots of pointless edits is effectively discouraged.

Comment: @jcuenod That's only true when bad edits get rejected.  They don't; they get accepted, so this fails as a deterrent.

Comment: If people are making bad edits because they want "Easy" rep, they still will but have to make more when they do get rejected.

Comment: @JoeW I disagree, if you don't gain by making bad edits, there's no point in making more of them. Like I say, it only takes 1 in 5 accurate edit rejections. What will happen instead is that they will make better edit suggestions for the same "easy rep" (except then, we won't mind).

Comment: @Servy right now all that happens is that they get accepted. What I'm suggesting will mean that just 1 rejection effectively nullifies 5 bad approvals.

Comment: And when they're getting accepted, *that doesn't matter*.

Comment: Ja but the reason the suggestions are being made is "easy" rep. So it does matter.

Comment: Here's the problem I have with this suggestion, as an editor who is still suggesting edits: Times when the OP rejects a perfectly valid edit just because they don't want it edited. Case in point: I have two rejected edits, one for a conflict and one that happened a couple days ago. The one a couple days ago was to remove a meta complaint about not being able to put "problem" in the title. The OP rejected it because he wanted to, even though he had already brought the issue up on Meta. A perfectly valid edit, one which another user made later, which would block me from edit rep for 5 edits.

Comment: In other words, this change could easily punish well-meaning editors and editors that are making valid edits just because the OP doesn't understand how editing works here, or similar. Though in my case the OP knew better, a lot of new users don't understand off the bat how editing works here and if a lower rep user tries to edit their question, the OP would have the option to reject.

Comment: @Kendra are you editing for rep though? I don't think so.

Comment: @jcuenod Does it matter? That rep is a nice bonus to me as an editor editing to help. I don't gain rep very quickly as I'm not knowledgable, or fast, enough to answer questions right now and I try not to ask questions unless I'm completely out of options. This suggestion would hinder good users like me who are actively and helpfully contributing in the best way we can.

Comment: @Kendra fair point but I the number of invalid rejections is far exceeded by the number of invalid approvals. Also, it would be easy to just exclude an OPs edit rejection from this calculation.

Comment: And how are invalid approvals countered by a feature like this? If anything, this feature encourages invalid approvals.

Comment: @jcuenod Excluding the OPs edit rejection would create further problems. There are instances of people trying to vandalize other people's posts. If the OP rejects them and those rejects are excluded, then your suggestion is completely missing on discouraging the behavior, as the editor will not take any hit. As for invalid rejections being low, for editors like me who try to not edit unless they absolutely know they're making a valid edit, that one invalid reject on occasion can _still_ completely devastate any rep gains I might have had for a few months at a time.

Comment: @Kendra vandalism is another issue entirely and so obviously a solution designed for another problem is not going to solve it. So as a low rep user, the point is you're less trusted on the site - it makes sense not to trust you.

Comment: Imho, a system to improve edits and encourage good edits/punish bad edits is really needed in SO. I suggested something too, and it was (as this question will probably be) downvoted into oblivion and deleted. I think that having several people suggesting the same idea (with different approaches) should raise some flags and spark a real debate in the community

Comment: Several people out of a massive userbase. Let's say 3 people suggest inverting the site's colors, they get downvoted into oblivion because the suggestion is rediculous. Should that suggestion still spark a real debate because multiple people suggested it?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro That's a fair thought- But let's look at it this way, too: Several people suggested these. Far more downvoted them as bad ideas. If each user can only downvote a question one time, how many downvotes does any one of the similar suggestions have to receive before it revokes those raised flags as "the community clearly does _not_ support this idea"? You have to look at both sides of that- Downvotes on feature-request meta questions are generally used for disagreement. (Of course, there are cases of poorly researched or horribly written feature-requests.)

Comment: @Kendra The problem is not the suggestion (that may be good or bad) but what triggered that suggestion. Downvoting a suggestion doesn't mean that the problem doesn't exist, it means that the community didn't support that particular suggestion. Maybe if those questions were not deleted, then other users would stop asking them... but they are deleted, and the topic comes back.

Comment: @Cerbrus If the colors in the site didn't have a good contrast and were not accessible, and somebody suggested changing them to pink, his/hers idea would be downvoted by the community (for being ridiculous), but that wouldn't change the fact that the site was not accessible (the real problem). SE has a big user base, but that doesn't mean that the suggestion of one user should be disdained because it was made by a single user. Maybe jcuenod's idea is not the best, but the underlying issue (poor edits getting approved) is still there

Comment: I'm not saying there isn't a problem. However, unless you can come up with a _good_ solution, there isn't much to discuss.

Answer (score 9):

I don't agree with this suggestion.

SO's rep system is for a large part based on positive feedback.
Sure, downvotes will lose you some rep, but that amount is insignificant to how much you receive for 1 upvote.

An addition like this feels like "punishment". It'd only serve to discourage users from suggesting edits completely.

When too many edit suggestions get rejected, a user will already get blocked from suggesting edits (afaik).
Requiring any amount of accepted suggestions before you can gain rep again can be very confusing, not to mention frustrating if someone invalidates a decent (/good) edit.

It will end up punishing users with good intentions to an extent that they may stop suggesting edits.

Comment: It is a punishment: for bad editing. It also doesn't cost any rep at all. I didn't know that users get blocked from editing if they have too many rejections. I honestly don't think users who are making good edits will be negatively affected by this - the general problem is that bad edits get rejected not that good edits do.

Comment: @Cerbrus How would punishing users that made bad edits (even if with good intentions) stop them from suggesting edits? Do downvotes in bad question deter people from keep asking questions?

Comment: @jcuenod Users who make good edits but only when they know it's a good edit and therefore don't edit incredibly often will be negatively affected by this, potentially to the point of not wanting to edit ever again. (I personally wouldn't stop editing because of such a thing, but it would be a stupid thing to do to a positively contributing user.) Also! Moderators [can now manually ban users from suggesting edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221832/) so why would we want to risk hurting good editors when bad editors can already be stopped/discouraged?

Comment: @jcuenod: it does cost the user rep he would otherwise have gained from perfectly good edits, just because someone invalidated an edit that may have been perfectly fine. I've had plenty of my proper edits invalidated, back in the day. Either by the OP, or reviewers that simply didn't pay attention.

Comment: Good edits get approved. The problem is really not good edits being rejected.

Comment: If good edits are being rejected en masse, then I'm happy to say that this is a bad idea.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: This feature would punish users not only for that specific edit, but also for a couple of edits afterwards. It's excessive. Excessive punishment is a damn good way to demotivate someone.

Comment: @jcuenod: Enough good edits get rejected to make a measure _this_ severe a bad idea.

Comment: @Cerbrus I understand that this feature is too harsh and not good. But I personally think that a less harsh solution is needed. And involving punishment (stronger than blocking for editing) should be an option. Not everything in life are prizes.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: Feel free to post a suggestion on the meta here.

Comment: I did. It was downvoted and deleted (not by me)

Comment: Then maybe it wasn't such a good idea. But that's beside the point of this question.

Comment: The fact that more than one and more than two people are suggesting the same thing (with different approaches) should make the community think that there is something going wrong. Downvoting and deleting the questions/suggestions will not change that fact

Comment: @Cerbrus I had a look at your history and I see that you have had 16 edits rejected (some of which, admittedly, I disagree with). None that I looked at were tag wiki edits which means none would have affected your rep. Conversely, you've had 113 accepted. Just saying.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: do you have _any_ idea how massive the SE community is? 2 people suggesting something doesn't mean that something _has_ to change. Besides, obviously more people disagree with the suggestion than that there are people agreeing, otherwise, the questions would score positive in votes. This answer is perfectly fine. I don't have to come up with an alternative to an bad idea, in order to criticize that bad idea.

Comment: @jcuenod: I'm not sure what you're trying to say there.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm saying that users who are using the system well are not going to be penalised by this and the penalisation is so minimal that at worst, a handful of people with reps < 2000, who would have made positive edits won't. I really don't see how this is a bad suggestion.

Comment: @jcuenod: Okay, I had about 130 edits there. 16 of those were rejected. If this feature were to be implemented, I'd wouldn't have gotten any rep for (16*5) ___`80`!!!___ out of my `113` accepted edits. Only 33 of my edits would have gotten me rep. Did I mention excessive punishment?

Comment: @Cerbrus you wouldn't get rep from any of them because you're >2000. What's more not every edit rejection was invalid IMHO.

Comment: Users that are currently below 2k will have the same problem. A _massive_ portion of their suggested edits will not get them any rep.

Comment: Users below 2k are not trusted on the site - that's the point. This stops them from getting there by making pointless edits.

Comment: So we remove the only benefit <2k users get from suggestion edits, just because they can't edit themselves, yet?

Comment: If they make worthwhile edits, I honestly think they're not going to be penalised. Just to clarify, I don't think the discussion is going anywhere so I'll leave it at this

Comment: _"This stops them from getting there by making pointless edits."_ Just a small clarification here, @jcuenod: You can only gain up to 1k rep from editing. After that, suggested edits, even if you are below 2k rep, do not gain you rep. If this is the only way these users are gaining rep, they will never get the full edit privilege. So that particular point doesn't really work out. They would still have to show they can ask or answer questions well to be able to have full editing privileges.

Comment: @jcuenod I'd have had no reputation at all from edits (subject to timing issues). You can bet I'd not have edited more than six or seven questions. That would give me great practice for when  2000 finally arrived, wouldn't it?