# How should I handle a suggested edit with "Comment: gerhdtcfjvygkbuhnj" as the edit summary?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, specific-edit

Suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22896266

Screenshot:

[image]

How do I tell the editor that "gerhdtcfjvygkbuhnj" is not a useful comment for an edit? Reject and edit the comment? Or is it not a problem and I should simply improve the edit?

Comment: By rejecting the edit with a custom rejection message.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Should we really reject an edit that (even without an explanation) looks fine just due to the explanation? I mean, it's just a formatting and spelling correction edit. No need to come up with a detailed reasoning why it's a good edit.

Comment: @BDL: it is indicative of a lack of care, boredom and respect for the rest of the community reviewing these edits. In this specific case, there was a larger problem and the account is now gone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and what was the problem?

Comment: @Sanyash: sorry, I can't go into details on that.

Comment: @BDL [Some edit summaries are bad enough to warrant rejection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364891/2751851). On a more general note, I feel the importance of edit summaries is sometimes overlooked. I have seen quite a few Meta controversies that could have been avoided by a clear summary indicating the point of an edit.

Comment: @BDL It doesn't need to be highly detailed but one or two words describing one of the improvements made would have been enough: "Added spacing" or even just "Formatting".

Comment: @MartijnPieters or BDL: Please consider putting that as an answer. Rejection seems like it would be the correct answer, and so is getting more upvotes here in comments, than the only actual answer.

Comment: "Edited post content" much better.

Comment: Moderators usually get custom flags with "mmmmmmmmmmmmmm", which are declined with the standard decline reason "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn" ([src](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33025602#33025602))

Comment: @BhargavRao I wonder if it's an old meme or something real.

Comment: And, if the edit looks OK without comment, isn't it good to click Improve Edit, and edit the comment?

Comment: @FZs You can't edit the edit summary. Their edit will get accepted with that edit summary and any improvement you make goes up with its own edit summary. The only way to prevent a bad edit summary from being saved is to reject the entire edit.

Comment: Does the editor not realise that the comment field is optional? Perhaps they felt the edit speaks for itself and put some junk in there just to satisfy a perceived requirement for a comment?

Comment: @AJFaraday it's only optional if you have full edit privilege (2k rep on SO). Suggested edits *requires* **manual** input for edit comment.

Comment: Considering the fact that it seems that there was a larger problem with the said user (multiple accounts with boosted reps from "usefull edit" maybe or whatever). I'am wondering if the community should really state on that question ? It is clair that someone with good faith that take the time to properly edit would put a fast "improve grammar/english" note instead of "akjhzkahz".

Comment: It may be the editor's *cat* who needs to be told.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In a case like this it seems like it would be a good use of pinging the editor by leaving a comment on the post to explain to them the purpose of the comment fields on a post edit. Overall the edit looks good and it appears that they just don't fully understand the purpose of the comment.

Comment: Pinging the editor works in this case only becaue the edit was approved. Before the edit is approved, you can't ping the author of a suggested edit.

Comment: You understand me correctly. The body of edit is rather good, the comment is the only problem, that's why I didn't reject it and asked on meta.

Comment: @yivi personally I would be a bit confused if a good edit got rejected because of a bad edit comment.

Comment: I'm not saying that. But the OP saw the comment during review. At that point, leaving a comment and pinging the editor was not an option.

Comment: You can't pin the author of this particular edit however - they're anonymous.

Comment: @JackBashford There were other problems with the account and [it was deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384441/how-to-handle-a-suggested-edit-with-comment-gerhdtcfjvygkbuhnj-as-the-edit-su#comment692525_384441)

Comment: It looks more like they did a keyboard mash because they didn't feel like writing a description than they don't know.

Comment: AFAIK, the asdlkfjldsajf and a generic "improving formatting" would be the same. The edit is too self evident an improvement of the post.

Answer (score 17):

Edits should only be rejected when they are not improving the post or when it is unclear why an edit has been made. When it is totally clear why an edit is being made (fixing capitalization, adding basic formatting, ...) an explanation is not necessarily required.

Note, that most of these edits contain an explanation stating something along the line of "Improved formatting", "Fixed spelling" which don't add any additional value.

The quality of the edit description comes into play only when it is unclear why an edit was necessary. For example, when content from a comment gets added to the post, then it is important to state where this content came from.

I would reject an edit that adds something new to the question when there is no explanation for it. I would accept an edit that only changes formatting no matter what the description states.

Comment: What if I put a spam link as an edit summary on an otherwise valid "improved formatting" edit suggestion?

Comment: @AndrewT. The comment becomes the edit summary in the page history. Luckily such a link would remain inert; the UI does not parse edit summaries in any way, so the spam link is not clickable, search engines will not find it and add to the target's page rank. Still, it would indicate a problem with the account that made the suggestion, so as a moderator, I'd very much would like to hear about such behaviour. (Moderators can change edit summaries too, so if it's something *offensive* then we can also help clean that up).

Comment: Agreed. As a special note, I always make sure to reject edits which mislead, by listing something benign like  "Improved formatting" as the edit summary when they also did something more significant (like alter the title or tags). Often, the major edits don't make sense in those cases, anyway.

Comment: @jpaugh That's the kneejerk reaction that doesn't help. If I improved formatting and also fixed the capitalization of i in the title, would you reject my edit?

Comment: @Braiam I'm specifically referring to cases where there are major edits, but only minor edits are mentioned in the subject; like if the title is rewritten, and it says, "grammar fixes." As an attempt to somehow "hide" or distract the reviewer from a more significant edit, it's tantamount to vandalism, even if the author was merely careless rather than intentionally vandalizing.

Comment: @jpaugh what you consider a major edit? What is a minor edit? [Is Bill edit major](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1233466/revisions)? Is [my edit a minor one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29965036/revisions)? Trying to draw lines in the sand isn't useful. And edit should be considered by whenever or not it objectively improves the post. Any other metric is bound to produce undesired effects.

Comment: @AndrewT. I think that's a bit of a special case. I'd think quite a few decisions would differ from usual in the case of outright spam rather than just useless or unhelpful information.

Comment: @Braiam I say a "major" edit is one that changes the content/meaning of the post, rephrases it, or changes the tags. It must be semantically checked for accuracy, and read very carefully. A "minor" one improves the existing content (spellcheck, formatting, spacing, etc). It's much easier to scan quickly, for the price that small semantic changes might be overlooked. Both linked edits are major, and the edit description should mention the most dramatic change (ideally, first). *No description* is actually better than one which claims to be minor, but isn't, because it must be read carefully.

Comment: @jpaugh any edit change the content of the post. That's not useful. Nor its useful the others metrics. Stack Exchange wants you to objectively look at the edit and tell if it improves the post or not. Your method is very arbitrary and wouldn't benefit the future reader at all.

Comment: @Braiam You're right that this rule might be hard to communicate to the whole community of editors, or even reviewers; you might also point out that I could read every edit carefully, and review far fewer of them. But I assume that some (many?) reviewers will quickly scan any edits described as non content-altering, without thinking further about it. That's why I believe edit descriptions that don't mention major edits are much more harmful than missing descriptions. It's a habit that should be discouraged.

Comment: @Braiam Please substitute "meaning" for content in my comments. Not every edit changes the meaning. I agree that it is arbitrary where the line is drawn, but I think drawing a line is still more useful than not.

Answer (score -9):

Reject the edit with a custom message explaining that [a gibberish comment is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384441/how-should-i-handle-a-suggested-edit-with-comment-gerhdtcfjvygkbuhnj-as-the-e/384480?noredirect=1#comment692525_384441) "indicative of a lack of care, boredom and respect for the rest of the community reviewing these edits", per Martijn Pieters.

Comment: By *custom* do you mean the *cause harm* option? Thats the only way I can see to enter a message. Is that message then passed back to the person suggesting the edit?

Comment: @DaleBurrell - Yes, that's the causes harm option. The reason you enter is then visible on the edit review. I think the user gets pinged about their edit getting rejected as well.

Comment: ["Causes harm" *is* the custom rejection reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355280/another-suggested-edit-reject-reason-when-much-of-the-post-is-left-in-a-mess#comment505462_355280). Confusion over that led to [this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274093/edit-reject-reasons-replace-causes-harm-with-other), and also [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356344/clarify-suggested-edit-rejection-reasons-by-changing-causes-harm-to-custom-re).

Comment: If the edit ends up being approved, despite one rejection with a custom reason, does the editor still see that custom reject reason?

Comment: The editor won't see the custom reason unless they go back at a later date to check the status of the review. There is no notification to the user if an edit they make gets rejected.