# Should I approve edits that only add '?' to the question title?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits, editing-help

I have been seeing [some edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23365388) that only add "?" to the end of the question's title.

The question starts with "How" so this means that is a question, to which adding "?" is correct, but at the same time, it doesn't change anything of the question; you can still understand everything.

Is adding "?" to the question's title is considered "no improvement whatsoever"? Or it's cosidered grammar mistakes correction?

Comment: A mod rejected that edit after you posted this question, so I guess you have your answer.

Comment: I wonder how this edit could circumvent the minimum 6 charracter rule.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ in the title, only one letter is enough.

Comment: Such mass edits are not ok ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6538067/shashankk-shekar-chaturvedi?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) are many of them just appending `?` to title, some are approved), clearly abuse of the system, not sure why thought. Are edits gives reputation or some other sort of *score* which someone wants to get? Probably badges..

Comment: @Sinatr You can [earn](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) +2 rep per edit if your suggested edits are accepted (up to 1k reputation gain in total).

Comment: @altocumulus, thanks, now I know the way to rise my initial reputation quickly on other stackexchange sites (unless their reward system are different) ;) jk

Comment: I actually still wonder about the need to add a question mark to the end of a title of the form "How to do x.". In my opinion, adding a question mark makes it seem like the OP would like to tell us how to do it. I may be wrong, but that's how I view it. A title with "How" should in my opinion end with a period.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

No, you should not be approving suggested edits that just add a ? to the title. This is clear if we look at the description of "No improvement whatsoever":

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

This change was just superfluous. Also from [How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it.

Those particular edits, that add just a question mark in the title certainly aren't substantial.

Comment: we did not coordinate this well ;)

Comment: I had typed out my answer 40 mins back, and clicked "Post Answer", but apparently there was a "Human Verification CAPTCHA" which I hadn't noticed. Saw it now while cleaning tabs. Sorry bout that.

Comment: The reason I think of approving is `To fix grammar and spelling mistakes`, because if you look ate the grammar, you are correcting it, but at the same time, it makes no difference.

Comment: meh, as you can see I put a lot of effort into my answer. I was thinking of ways to puff it out and couldn't. Yours is better.

Comment: @Vencovsky I really badly want to fix your comment about eating grammar :D

Comment: @YvetteColomb sorry, not english native speaker

Comment: @Vencovsky, Adding a question mark at the end is just a trivial punctuation fix, and does not contribute to a "significant" edit. Also, suggested edits like those are troublesome for another reason, given the fact that it requires two human users to review them, who could spend their time reviewing other edits that actually solve valid issues with a post. If those edits are rejected, they send back a message to the user that they should not be suggesting these kinds of edits.

Comment: @Vencovsky you said "because if you look ate the grammar," instead of "at grammar". It made me smile. Your English is very good. I admire people who can speak multiple languages

Comment: @YvetteColomb I like people that corrects grammar, at least i'm learning something.

Comment: What gets me is when people put periods at the end of a question.

Comment: What about @jpmc26 answer?

Comment: @Vencovsky it is left to the community to decide which answer is correct.

Comment: Can we skip the wooly language about superfluous/substantial?  The real answer is hidden in the comments: "given that it requires two human users to review".  The question mark is certainly an improvement --- correct, impossible-to-misunderstand writing should be the goal --- but we are collectively annoyed at the human time such an edit eats vs. value added.  If it is a problem, the solution is adding a grammar bot that suggests when a user should be adding a question mark to the title.

Answer (score 9):

Making a suggested edit to add a question mark to a title and nothing else is not ok. If all else in the question is ok, leave the question and find something that needs more help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the UI make it clear that we have a different standard for editing when a user's edits require review?

Comment: @canon it doesn't nor should it.  There shouldn't be a different standard.  If it is a good edit, it is a good edit.  The system is just more tolerant of superfluous edits from users with full edit privileges

Comment: @psubsee2003 I'd imagine that fixing punctuation would seem reasonable to most people. The only issue here _appears_ to be that a newer user must make their edit worth a reviewer's time. I'm asking whether that's conveyed through the UI and you say,  _"it doesn't nor should it."_ I suppose it's not important to set expectations...

Comment: "If all else in the question is ok" What question? If it doesn't end with a question mark, it isn't a question. :P

Answer (score 9):

The mods are wrong here, or at least aren't giving the full story. [Minor edits that improve something are good.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253326/1394393)

You should approve the edit **if the title is a full, grammatical question**. Without the question mark, a full question as a title is just wrong punctuation-wise. In these cases, it was probably left off as a typo. There's no reason to leave a question without correct punctuation when it's otherwise formally correct. Making language conform to English language norms and rules *is* a substantial improvement, no matter how small the edit actually is.

If not, you may either edit the question title yourself to make it grammatical, or you may leave it alone if it isn't doesn't seem weird to read.

This specific edit doesn't qualify for approval based on that evaluation, but others will.

The only remotely reasonable argument anyone has presented here against approving these kinds of edits is that the reviewers have to spend time approving them. But this doesn't validate their point because reviewers have to spend time rejecting them, too. Since the edit is so small, these are much quicker to review than larger edits; there are nearly no time savings by rejecting them. This is especially true since the Suggested Edit queue is small. I suspect that much more time is spent agonizing over rejecting an actual improvement trying to decide if it's "too minor" than would be spent by simply approving them when they're correct. I know that would certainly be the case for me if I tried to adhere to such a policy.

Comment: Now I'm confused

Comment: Enter discussion on the meaning of substantial here...

Comment: Also these kind if edits are no problem when done by someone with full editing privileges IMO. Doing this through a suggested edit is just a waste of at least 2 reviewers their time.

Comment: @Luuklag Agreed.  Once you have editing privileges, go ahead and make small improvements.  But if your changes are going to require other people to approve them, make it worth their time.

Comment: @Luuklag Doesn't matter. The appropriateness of an edit should not depend on who makes it. If the system is broken, [fix the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294026/1394393); don't leave low quality content lying around. An edit is either an improvement or not.

Comment: [Suggested edit was this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23365388) - Now let's check what the English language tells us about it: [**Adding a question mark to the end of a "How to": is this practice defensible?**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14396/how-to-and-where-to-questions-that-are-not-questions-is-this)

Comment: @Cœur I didn't say the OP should approve this specific edit. I gave the general rule for evaluating such edits. This is in contrast to the moderators who answered saying that *all* edits adding a question mark should be rejected.

Comment: @Vencovsky This is a long standing disagreement because our edit approval system has well known problems that SO has refused to spend any time addressing for years. It's not surprising that you're confused.

Comment: @Vencovsky "Now I'm confused." In other words, when deciding whether an edit is substantial enough, whether it "makes the post event a little bit easier to read," you often have to use your own best judgement, and even high-rep users disagree. Of course, you can always skip a review, and see how others handle it.

Comment: Titles are like newspaper headlines -- they often sacrifice grammar for terseness. Yet no one has trouble understanding them. While making it grammatical is an improvement, it doesn't actually fix anything that was seriously broken in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar Then I guess it's not important for a post to be grammatical, either, since that doesn't preclude understanding. It's not a question of "seriously broken." It's a question of whether it's high quality or not. A newspaper wouldn't publish an article with a question that's a grammatically correct sentence without a question mark, either. They'll either abbreviate it to something clearly not a full sentence or they'll include the mark.

Comment: I don't edit posts just to correct grammar, although I've seen others do so. If I'm editing a post for some other reason, I may also fix their grammar if it's really eggregious. I'll usually edit titles to fix typos, since they impact searching.

Comment: As others have pointed it, if you don't have full edit privileges, you're also imposing on others to approve your edits. So it's not just your own time.

Comment: @Barmar And as I've pointed out, whether something is an improvement or not is completely orthogonal to the reputation and privileges of the user. If you don't like reviewing minor edits, advocate for changes to the system or avoid the edit queue. Rejecting them takes just as much time as approving them, so there's zero savings by rejecting them. Furthermore, the suggested edits queue is rather small anyway, as noted in the question I linked. So the savings would be minimal even if they existed due to volume. Let people who want to improve things do it.

Comment: @jpmc26 actually there is a difference in what is considered ok as an edit vs a suggested edit.  For eg It is commonly accepted that retagging in burninations are only done by people . with full edit privileges. People without them are advised not to make the edits.

Comment: @YvetteColomb That is because coordinated burn activities necessarily generate a high volume of edits. (They're *supposed* to be large edits when the question has need of them, not just tag edits.) That reasoning doesn't apply here. And if we ever reach the point where we have too many people suggesting minor improvements that are actually good changes to the site, I'll eat one of my hats.

Comment: don't eat your hat - not good for the digestion

Comment: BTW, most people don't consider full grammatical questions to be the best type of title for some reason: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/311903#311903 even though the website guidelines do.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心996ICU六四事件 [There's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25019057/1394393) [nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42283014/1394393) [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28977651/1394393) [with a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11973239/1394393) [grammatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35493056/1394393) [and mechanically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14464901/1394393) [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38663759/1394393) [title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14741397/1394393). That answer has several problems that contribute to it being downvoted.