# Improve/edit answer with single character but critical

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, suggested-edits

What should I do if there's a single char error but critical. Like + sign instead of = which is critical for the code and I don't have enough reputation to comment. I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292243/please-dont-just-approve-trivial-suggested-edits-rather-improve-the-edit-per-th) related post but it does not address this issue. Thank you.

Comment: If you mention *where* this critical error is, perhaps someone else can address it for you?

Comment: Are you sure there's really absolutely nothing else you can improve in the post?

Comment: Other improvements will be trivial which is discouraged. And the other alternative @jonrsharpe mentioned will address one such answer.

Comment: Are you asking in the generic or specific?

Comment: Generic. I posted an alternative answer to that specific post.

Comment: The reason that making trivial edits is discouraged is to keep you from suggesting a bunch of trivial edits. If you have a compelling reason to make the edit (like fixing a typo in the code), then you *should* fix other problems with the post, whether they would otherwise be trivial or not. Otherwise, you would be wasting the time of the people who reviewed your edit, even more so than if you were suggesting trivial edits. This is the spirit of the line in the documentation, and the whole reason for a prohibition on suggesting edits < 6 characters in length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

- leave a comment to inform both the OP and visitors of the issue
- edit if you have [edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)
- make a substantial edit, if you can, fixing all other issues, besides the single typo.
- post a better answer
- hop into an on-topic [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) to seek help from other members
- downvote (if the typo makes the answer not useful)

Based on what you're capable of pick one of the above options.

Comment: This list leaves out the most important and most appropriate option: fix the other problems with the post at the same time.

Comment: @CodyGray I assumed that scenario didn't apply here based on what the OP gave me to go on but I'm okay with your suggestion so added that as well.