# Can we make approving suggested edits harder?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I just read and thought about [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/292243/1025391), about how to deal with suggested edits that may or may not be "too minor" and reviewers that blindly approve anything that doesn't effectively harm the posts expressiveness but can safely be considered pointless or redundant after all. I think "reject", or better "reject and edit" should be the course of action in such cases. And so I found this question:

- [Can we make rejecting suggested edits easier?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258397/1025391)

In my question I'd like to pick up the idea given in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258450/1025391). To make approval of a suggested edit a little more complicated.

I'd like to suggest adding a set of check boxes to the approval UI, similar to the reject reason you have to pick when you reject an edit. I'd like to have reviewers to pick from a set of reasons *why* they approve an edit:

- The edit fixes grammatical or spelling mistakes.
- The edit clarifies the meaning of the post without changing it.
- The edit corrects minor mistakes or adds addendums / updates as the post ages.
- Other: ...

(I populated this list from the [detail page on the edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) about *when to edit posts*. Feel free to think of more options.)

I feel this approach would incentivize reviewers to think more about their approval and thus lead to better justified actions. It would educate reviewers and thus strengthen the common understanding of the desired edit quality we, as a community, want to see on this site. Maybe this addition would allow for more differentiated auditability of approvals in the future.

The hard part in performing a review never was to *make the required clicks* but to *make the review decision*. And this suggestion does not alter this relation. The clicking will obviously be harder than it is now (around 2 more clicks). But the decision making could actually turn out to be easier when you can check against a list of criteria that can guide your decision.

I do not argue that an edit, however tiny, should be approved if it improves the post. I do not say that editors should not receive their reward, that contribute only a minor improvement. But an edit, that does not improve the post *at all*, should be rejected. Which is currently often not done.

I can't believe that placing around two more clicks makes the approval too complicated. Note that the edit summary that comes with each edit should already provide a hint what item(s) to check. I think that reviewers should be required to put as much effort into approving as into rejecting an edit. If this tiny additional step, that is to state the reason why one came to a decision just made, makes the process too complicated for a reviewer, he might just not be the right person to do the job.

After looking at the number of pending suggested edits in the SO review queue, I came to the conclusion that reviewer time is not an overly scarce resource. So maybe the additional burden of around 2 more clicks per review decision will not crash the system.

What is a peer review without meaningful feedback to the editor? As a follow-up these "qualified approvals" could be fed back to the editors (similar to the [reject-notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120624/179891)) to promote our sense of edit quality to these unexperienced editors (having less than 2k rep). How awesome would it feel to get feedback for your first edits (*"Nice! You've fixed spelling or grammar mistakes!"* or *"Great! You've clarified the meaning of the post without changing it!"*).

After all, the absence of an approval reason for trivial edits in above list (e.g., *"This edit does neither improve nor harm the expressiveness of the post."*) might eventually lead to a decreasing number of these to bother us.

[In this sense](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

Comment: Alas, I'm afraid review drones will only choose the first approval reason in all cases. The worst of them don't even *read* the edit they're approving, there is no way they would be bothered by a few checkboxes.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi At least this approach would make such behavior more obvious (maybe even testable). In the best case, this would lead them to think more about their actions. I find this perspective very promising.

Comment: Eliminating the review badges would probably go a long way toward killing the robo-reviewers.

Comment: Oh yeah... Let's add another nitpicking feature to make the network even more nitpicking.

Comment: Maybe an approval reason like _"This edit turned an awful mess into a shining example of how to make up a question on this site."_ together with a badge for receiving a number of these would line up well with this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's already a minimum character limit for edits when you have below 2,000 reputation.

Comment: @TylerH 6 characters, if I remember right.

Comment: Approving **should be easier** than reject. The goal is to **improve** the site, if you raise all kinds of overbearing barriers then people will simply stop investing their time. And people who think that reviewers are in it for the badges are delusional; there are far easier ways to gain badges on SO.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Either they're in it for the badges, or they just like hitting 'approve'...

Comment: @Scimonster Or people think that these small edits are OK and should be accepted; IIRC since the removal of _too minor_ trivial edits should also be OK, see also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253123/when-an-edit-only-fixes-a-typo-what-should-i-do-as-a-reviewer

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I guess you've never gone across the people who approve *actively harmful* edits.

Comment: @Scimonster The premiss of this question (and the linked question that triggered it) is not actively harmful edits. It is about trivial edits where it is more a matter of **opinion** if it is an improvement or not. Sure people should pay attention when reviewing the edit queue (I never said they shouldn't), but making it harder will be counterproductive as productive, contributing members of the community will stop bothering with reviews.

Comment: I thoroughly approve of this. Please make all the people editing only "thanks" out of questions (leaving all the other errors there) disappear.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Are you arguing about my wording or about my point? The hardness in making a review decision is not the number of clicks required, but to distinguish between _good_ or _bad_. Once the decision is made it should be easy enough to give a single-click indicator about the quality of the edit while not deterring anyone from reviewing. The goal of the suggestion is also to improve the site, but by improving the review process (an approach to which we are discussing here). Do you think the review process is perfect?

Comment: The one thing I find rather annoying about the editing process is when I want to make a real edit, and I can't, because some trivial edit of like one or two characters is pending, and even if I reject it, it needs two more rejects before its cleared. So until the junk edit is rejected (or approved), no real edit can be made.

Comment: The default approval reason should be "The edit makes a change that this reviewer ignored."  Review-ban the robo-reviewers who approve 3 edits without changing the reason to a legitimate reason.

Comment: @developerwjk You _could_ select "Reject and Edit" in those cases, considering you think the edit in question should not be approved to begin with. This way, you get to edit, and the edit gets rejected. I would say if the edit makes a change you were going to make yourself in your edit, even if it was small, then you should select "Improve Edit" instead. But of course, that's your call.

Comment: As an editor who must still be peer reviewed, I would truly like this. I look at the responses each of my suggested edits get to see how well accepted they were, however with all the talk of "robo-reviewers" in that queue, it makes it hard to know if my edits really are good edits or not. This would provide me a little more feedback, and give me a more clear indication of what I've done right in my edits and therefore should keep doing.

Comment: @Kendra I would like the option to leave custom comments on a review item when I accept, purely for the purpose you've pointed out.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder how many of the incorrectly approved edits come not from roboreviewers, but from reviewers who really think they did the right thing. I think this suggestion would help with that too.

Comment: After hitting 2k this week and finally seeing some of the shite that gets suggested, I think _suggesting_ edits should be made harder.

Answer (score 40):

I think that your proposed idea, of having to explain why to approve each edit, would get to be too much of a burden on legitimate reviewers. But I definitely agree that it should take extra clicks to approve a bad edit.

I made a suggestion to this effect [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted/240548#240548). The gist of the post is:

> If an edit has any reject votes, show a warning while clicking approve. It would say something like "This edit already has x reject votes. Are you sure you want to approve it?" It would have an "approve anyways" button there. Then there could be a line, and the standard reject form right there.

This is an extra click plus mouse move. That's a shocking amount of extra work for a roboreviewer. At the very least it will slow them down.

Comment: If you add "fix formatting" and "include information from comments in the question" to @moooeeeep 's list; you'd cover most of the edits I approve.  I don't see replacing a single Approve button with a list of Approve as X buttons as adding a large burden to the reviewer.  Especially since there're already similar lists for tossing bad questions/etc.

Comment: In addition to the point @DanNeely made, qualified approve reasons might make it easier to audit approve decisions and certainly will educate reviewers what they should be looking for when approving an edit.

Comment: The hard part in making a review is even with three more clicks not _to do the clicking_. It's making the decision. I don't agree that this would deter legitimate reviewers. It actually could make the decision easier, as you can check against a list of criteria for the approval decision.

Comment: I like to think of myself as a legitimate reviewer and having to pick a reason would not be a burden on me at all. Why would it be a burden?

Comment: @Radiodef Because then it's extra work to approve.

Comment: @Scimonster So what? Don't you think a legitimate reviewer should spend adequate time evaluating each item such that they have a reason to approve it? Clicking through a dialog takes at most 5 seconds.

Comment: While this is an interesting idea, I have some concerns about it. The main one being that reviews should be independent. If agreeing with the majority is easier, it might encourage a herd mentality. Related, it also introduces an order dependence. If I disagree with the majority, I have to provide a reason if there were other reviewers before me, but not if I happen to be the first reviewer. Also, in some review queues, the majority of the reviewers often does not vote according to site guidelines. So there isn't always a correlation between agreeing with the majority, and reviewing correctly.

Answer (score 12):

As someone who's somewhat active in the edit review queue, I would find it frustrating if I had to fill out an extra dialog for every edit I approved. Here's how I look at it - if you're paying attention and sincerely interested in getting the reviews right, it's frankly generally not that hard to tell a good edit from a bad one, so reviewing edits ***should be*** a quick and easy process.

To my eye, it's just people who *don't care* about paying enough attention to getting it right that cause the bulk of the problems with suggested edits. I feel that we'd be better off focusing on efforts to increase the ability to identify and act against both serial suggestors of poor edits and serial accepters of poor edits in the review queue.

Comment: The hard part in making a review is even with three more clicks not to do the clicking. It's making the decision. I don't agree that this would deter legitimate reviewers. It actually could make the decision easier, as you can check against a list of criteria for the approval decision.

Comment: Why would explaining your reasoning be frustrating? When you approve edits, don't you have a reason? Didn't you have to do this already for the many edits which you have presumably rejected? Also: *"I feel that we'd be better off focusing on efforts to increase the ability to identify and act against both serial suggestors of poor edits and serial accepters of poor edits in the review queue."* So do you have an alternative to suggest then? Since the idea in this question is targeted at identifying serial acceptors of poor edits.

Comment: I would find an extra dialog frustrating because it is simply added process slowing down what doesn't need to be a slow process. I feel strongly that the problem isn't with reviewers genuinely thinking bad edits are good, so I don't think a checklist to compare to will help - I think the problem is with bad editors just clicking through without caring,  and that they'll just click through one more screen too while it'll add (an admittedly small amount of) extra effort for those of us who don't really have any quality problems as it is.

Comment: How long does it take to click through a dialog when you know what you're looking for? 5 seconds? Probably less for an efficient reviewer. Experienced reviewers will have no problem with such a thing, inexperienced and bad reviewers will be forced to either stop and think or pick at random. The latter incurs a high degree of obvious error.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's hard - I'm just saying that I don't think that an added dialog would really stop the bad reviewers, and that I don't feel it adds value for reviewers already doing well. But that's just my opinion, you're welcome to take it or leave it.

Answer (score 1):

You keep saying that the hardness of a review is determining if it is good or bad and not clicking the button. But this just makes approving it MORE complicated because not only do you have to figure out if the edit is "good" but you have to categorize why and then apply the correct check boxes. This is just too onerous for not enough benefit.

I also don't understand why people are so gung-ho to reject edits that don't do anything *bad* but just don't change enough of the post. Should we leave minor errors just because there isn't anything more to fix? No. Is it just because they shouldn't get their two measly fake internet points when you don't think they've done enough work to earn it?

If an edit improves a post it is improved regardless of the magnitude of the change. If they make a really minor edit (like just change the tags) and skip over more work (like the actual post itself) then the proper response is "Reject and edit" and make the additional edits yourself. I think if you aren't prepared to put in the work then just approve the edit because it is still an improvement over doing nothing. Someone else can come along and make the rest of the edits later.

Comment: If an edit improves a post it should be approved. I do not argue that. I'm not saying editors that contribute only a tiny improvement should not receive their reward. But when an edit does not improve the post at all, it should be rejected (which is currently often not the case). I don't see how two more clicks make the review process more complicated as it is. I'm saying that reviewers should be required to take as much time to think about an approval as about a rejection.

Comment: If this tiny additional step (to state the reason how/why one came to a decision just made) makes the process too complicated for a reviewer, he might just not be the right person to do the job.

Comment: It isn't the clicks, it's the classification. It means I can't just look at an edit and say "yeah, that looks better." and click a button. I have to go through the process of figuring out exactly why the edit is good and which buckets it goes in. It is extra processing about something that is at least somewhat subjective and I just don't see that the benefits are worth it.

Comment: I think you get better at this quickly as you get experience with reviewing. Also, an edit description should already provide hints what buckets should apply (corrected tags, improved formatting, corrected spelling, etc.). When we accept bad suggested edits, we will see more bad edits when the editors are no longer reviewed.